# Is number of output filters right way to generate multiple output feature maps?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, u-net

I am doing a CNN U-Net localization network that works on a way of scalar regression of 2D plane using Gaussian peaks in Keras. I have dataset that contains 10 different keypoint PNG's (each about 50k samples), for which I have x/y as ground truth. Now I am expanding the network to also output 10 feature maps, one for each keypoint class. I previously generated only single filter Sigmoid 1x1 output layer, now I have modified the number of filters to 10, and changed nothing else.

Is modifying kernel's the main this to change the number of output feature maps? Are there any other modification the network could face with this change, maybe U-Net specifically? Shouldn't the last layer (excluding the output sigmoid 1x1) also undergo some changes in the U-Net?